# htaccess query rewrite first time

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have tried many of the query to / answers from google and stack overflow, but can't find one that works for me.

I have a file users.php, and when I send users.php?user=username, I want that to be users/user/username.  I already have the php extension removed in my .htaccess.

What's the best way to do this?  Also, help with the proper file structure required would be helpful.

Edit: Here's what I have so far:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# to make `/path/index.php` to /path/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s(.*/)index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule . %1 [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s.+\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [NE,R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^users/user/(.*)/$ users.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Comment: check my updated answer. it will give you uses/user/username format

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On     
RewriteRule    ^users/user/$    users.php?user=$1    [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hehe.. We all have the same answers! Try to remove all the code in your *.htaccess* file and then check this alone, just itself:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^users/user/([a-z0-9-_]+) /users.php?user=$1 [NC]
```

Use `[NC]` flag at the very end of the rule to be matched it in a case-insensitive manner. It means, the rule will doesn't care whether letters appear as upper-case or lower-case.

---

Now if the folder that containing your */users.php* is entitled with **/html**, give this a try:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^users/user/([a-z0-9-_]+) /html/users.php?user=$1 [NC]
```

Just change the **"html"** as the name of the folder containing your *users.php*.

---

Okay, lets check this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^users/user/([a-z0-9-_]+) /beta/users.php?user=$1 [NC]
```

But please always don't forget the `RewriteEngine on` and to comment what's happening. And the URL that you must be checked is the not existed URLs that we're trying to remap. *(Example: domain.com/users/user/name without a slash in the end.)*

Comment: I tried that just alone, and I get a 404 when I try to access domain.com/users/user/username.  I'm running a simple test to echo the username value at the page....

Comment: @user2252323 Okay, take a look inside your file manager, what is the name of the **Current folder** where your existed _/users.php_ is located?

Comment: it's on a shared server on GoDaddy, but it looks like the directory is "html".

Comment: Come on, check it clearly. The _index.php_ of mine in **cPanel**, is in **/public_html** folder, and the other _index_ on other hosting is in **/home/www/example.com**. Now what's yours?

Comment: I generated an error on purpose to see the path, and I got this: `/home/content/72/9996272/html/beta/index.php`.  I am testing the .htaccess on a subdirectory "beta" which is linked to a folder in the root directory, "beta"

Comment: @user2252323 Could you please link here your website? I just want to see it. Are you sure there's a `mod_rewrite` in your account?

Comment: @user2252323 Come on lets talk: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28210/servant